# Summation and binomial coefficient

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, combinations, sampling

I'm studying sampling at the moment, but I can't get the passage below:

When $n$ units are sampled from $N$ units without replacement, then each unit of the population
can occur with other units selected out of the remaining $(N - 1)$ units in the population and each unit occurs in $\binom{N-1}{n-1}$ of the $\binom{N}{n}$ possible samples. So

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i = 1}^{\binom{N}{n}} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right) = \binom{N - 1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^{N} y_i
\end{equation}

Are there any arguments/calculations that can help me understand better the passage above?

Comment: Are you sure the indexing is correct? The left hand side sums two times over $i$. The outer summation is summing constants.

Comment: The inner sum on the left-hand side must be wrong, since it's only over the first $n$ units of the population.  Should there be another subscript on $y_i$?

Comment: I'm reporting verbatim what's written in page 6 here: http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/sampling/chapter2-sampling-simple-random-sampling.pdf Is there any way to spot the mistake to make sense of these calculations?

Answer (score 0):

The notation in $$\sum_{i = 1}^{\binom{N}{n}} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right) = \binom{N - 1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^{N} y_i$$ is not good, but I think it is possible to find the intended meaning.

You start with a set of $N$ values presented as $y_i$.

- The initial $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\binom{N}{n}}$ counts over all the different ways of taking a combination of $n$ items from the big set: this is supposed to represent the possibilities in sampling without replacement.
- The $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i$ is then the sum of the $n$ items in each selected combination. I can see no justification for using the same index for the combinations  and each combination's individual items.
- The $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N y_i$ on the right-hand side is simply the sum of all the values in the big set.

The equality is not difficult to justify intuitively: each $y_i$ from the big set can appear in a total of ${\binom{N-1}{n-1}}$ different combinations, since if it is in a combination then the other elements of the combination fill be the $n-1$ space left, taken from the remaining $N-1$ values of the big set.